# C# Adding controls by a method, started from another class

Tags: c#, excel

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using _System = System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SOTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void AddTextbox()
        {
            _System.TextBox tb = new();
            Controls.Add(tb);
            MessageBox.Show("Test 2");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //this is working
            AddTextbox();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //here just "Test" & "Test2" are showing up, but no Textbox
            string appPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            appPath += "AL.xlsx";
            Excel excel = new (@"" + appPath + "", 1);
            excel.Something();
        }
    }

    class Excel
    {
        string path = "";

        _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb;
        Worksheet ws;
        public Excel(string path, int Sheet)
        {
            this.path = path;
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
            ws = wb.Worksheets[Sheet];
        }

        public void Something()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
            Form1 form1 = new();
            form1.AddTextbox();
        }
    }

}
```

Hello everyone,
im a beginner, kind of new to programming and actually im just trying few things with C# and Excel.
Right now im stuck with the code above. At all it's just some little part of my whole code, but this part is exactly my problem. Just this code is reproducing exactly the behaviour I don't understand.

The main idea is, that some method is supposed to do something with an Excel file and after getting all information, using that information back in Form class to do something.
Its working with a message box (for example), but not if I want to add some textbox or button for example.

If i try it by button1 inside the Form class its working fine.

If i try it by button2 by Excel class it's not working and I don't get why.
Because for real it's just refering back to Form class or not?
The code is running without any error, but the textbox is not created (or at least not added to the form).

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you have 2 usings of the same thing, twice?  `using _System = System.Windows.Forms;`  and `using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` vs the `using System.Windows.Forms;` etc.. ?

Comment: Because once for using and once as a shortcut, that I dont need to write "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" or  "System.Windows.Forms" in front off code, where it's needed to clarify.

Comment: Ah ok, but you can simply do the `using` only once with whatever alias you want and only reference the alias in your code.  You don't need to reference it twice.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, that I direct tried. But then I need to put that alias in front of any function. Before it was just needed to put it, when the compiler wasn't sure if to use from System or from Excel. So for me it seems, that it's the better way like it's written above. But maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I know your code is just part of your project, but as it is it wouldn't compile. The lines `Excel excel = new (@"" + appPath + "", 1);` and `Form1 form1 = new();` specifically.
Have you tried using `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` in your `AddTextbox` method?

Comment: Hello @Naylor, thank you for your suggestion, that I instant tried. Same behaviour. Nothing changed. Btw. I can compile this code (really only this code) without any errors. This code above I wrote specially for Stack Overflow, to show in a short way the behaviour I run into, in my code. I use .Net 5.0 + Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library as a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that instead of modifying the original `Form1` you are constructing a new `Form1` and adding a textbox to it.

If you added `form1.Show()` at the end of the `Something()` method you will see the new `Form1`. If you want to modify an existing form you will need to give the `Excel` class a reference to the form. Either by passing one into the constructor and storing it, or by passing it into the `Something` method.

Comment: Now I understand the issue. With form1.Show() I was able to exactly see, what you were describing. Now I will get into the topic of modifying existing forms. Thank you!